# Whati is the purpose of docker build output?

Tags: docker, build, continuous-integration, dockerfile

## What is the purpose and how to use:

`docker build --output`

[Description from Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

> --output , -o         API 1.40+
>   Output destination (format: type=local,dest=path)

## Reason for question:

I'm using docker as a build engine and I was hoping to find some why to export a file or variable during or after `docker build`. Would it help with that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`--output` flag is used to set output configuration for [`buildkit`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) image builder. `buildkit` is available from `docker 18.09` release. You need to use the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` to use buildkit currently.

`buildkit` itself supports build output to different destinations like a [docker image or local directory or as docker tar ball or oci format tar ball](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#output). But with `docker` cli tool, looks like you can export the build output only to a local directory.

**Syntax**

```
--output type=local,dest=path/to/output-dir
```

**Example**

```
root@vm1:~/cc# DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -o type=local,dest=/root/cc/out .
[+] Building 0.5s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 49B                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                      0.0s
 => [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu                                                                                               0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                        0.0s
 => exporting to client                                                                                                               0.5s
 => => copying files 64.40MB

# cd /root/cc/out
# ls -lrt
total 76
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 sys
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 proc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 home
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 boot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:09 srv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:09 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:09 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:09 media
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:10 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 12 13:10 dev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 bin
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 etc
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 lib
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 run
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 root
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 lib64
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 usr
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Jan 20 07:33 var
root@vm1:~/cc/out#
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so would it be possible to both, build image for upload to docker registry and also export it to local path in order to access build artifact?

Comment: @JacekStyrylski I need to do exactly the same. Did you solved it?

Comment: Did you check if `docker save` is useful for your purpose?

Comment: @henioStraszny You could do both outputs as two separate build commands. Docker will cache the build, so the second command would be almost instant.